# Changing Size in SizeChanged event does not take effect

Tags: c#, winforms, events, layout

**Technology: C#, Winforms**

**The Background:**
I have the following container structure (Form containing a panel, which contains 2 panels)

```
Form F1
 |-> Panel P1 (DockStyle.Fill)
        |-> Panel P2 (DockStyle.Top)
        |-> Panel P3 (DockStyle.Fill)
```

I register for P3.SizeChange event and in the event I change P2.Size

**The Problem:**
I expect all the size changes will be reflected correctly on the GUI

**Observed result:**
Every time P2.Size changes based on the previously set Size

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried calling PerformLayout and Invalidate, but still the GUI does not correctly reflect the changes.
2. If I hook up the same function to F1.SizeChange, it all works fine
3. Instead of changing the Size, if I change and revert the DockStyle (P3.Dock = DockStyle.None; P3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill), it messes up the GUI

Seems like in Forms library I cannot change a layout related property (Size, Dock, etc) from a sibling control's layout related event (SizeChanged)

Has anyone else encountered this issue and have a workaround?
I am using .NET 4.0 (I think) from Visual Studio Express 2010

Inputs will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The size of P3 is directly affected by the size of P2 so no surprise.  Post code.

Comment: But that holds true if I do it from F1.SizeChanged too, but it works from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the size in the next message loop iteration (which will happen after the layout pass ends) by doing it in `BeginInvoke()`.

Comment: I will try this and reply back. But this is at best hacky solution. Do you know why it behaves this way.

Comment: Indeed it works. Thanks a lot. Does anyone know why it does not work though

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you are trying to achieve; however If you are attempting to distribute the available space between P2 and P3 a `SplitContainer` could help solving the problem.

Comment: It is a complex GUI layout in which I am facing the issue. I have just extracted the root cause for illustration purposes.